# Interpret credible intervals / HPD following posterior sampling

Tags: r, bayesian, interpretation, credible-interval

I am unsure on how to interpret credible interval results. How can credible intervals consist of negative numbers when the collected data only consists of positive numbers? I would expect that, given data ranging anywhere from 1 to 20, the credible interval would tell me (with 95% certainty) that a value would be between *x* and *y* - where *x* and *y* are in between 1 and 20.

Should I add the general mean to the produced results to obtain what I am looking for?

In my reproducible example below, I generate the following data points:
X - dependent variable, random between 0 and 20
Y - condition variable
Z - study participant ID

I am then looking at the Y-A, Y-B, and Y-C rows of the "Quantiles for each variable" and find the following credible interval for Y-A: [-5.749, 0.495], as opposed to an interval between 1 and 20. Am I simply looking at the wrong data? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Reproducible example:

```
library(BayesFactor)
Data <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:20),
  Y = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  Z = sample(c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"), 20, replace = TRUE)
)
Data$Y <- as.factor(Data$Y)
Data$Z <- as.factor(Data$Z)

bayesfactor = anovaBF(X ~ Y + Z, data = Data, whichRandom = c("Z"))
bayesfactor
bayesfactor_posterior <- posterior(bayesfactor, iterations = 10000)
summary(bayesfactor_posterior)
```

My results:

```
Iterations = 1:10000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 10000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

         Mean     SD Naive SE Time-series SE
mu   10.63868  2.918  0.02918        0.02918
Y-A  -2.40507  1.616  0.01616        0.02169
Y-B  -0.47454  1.419  0.01419        0.01473
Y-C   2.87961  1.916  0.01916        0.02677
Z-P1  0.04134  3.245  0.03245        0.03199
Z-P2 -1.56066  3.111  0.03111        0.03111
Z-P3  2.96385  3.117  0.03117        0.03189
Z-P4 -1.59330  3.500  0.03500        0.03573
sig2 27.99127 10.851  0.10851        0.15682
g_Y   1.20403  8.990  0.08990        0.08990
g_Z   1.02143  1.652  0.01652        0.02174

2. Quantiles for each variable:

         2.5%     25%      50%     75%   97.5%
mu    4.83704  9.0158 10.66341 12.2694 16.4573
Y-A  -5.74906 -3.4504 -2.32914 -1.2821  0.4952
Y-B  -3.37089 -1.3441 -0.44655  0.4431  2.2909
Y-C  -0.49649  1.5046  2.75880  4.1339  6.8901
Z-P1 -6.34286 -1.8575  0.02995  1.9121  6.5346
Z-P2 -7.77506 -3.3115 -1.52214  0.2191  4.3945
Z-P3 -2.82042  1.1496  2.83577  4.7147  9.3355
Z-P4 -9.05500 -3.5174 -1.46395  0.5629  4.9008
sig2 14.07844 20.5537 25.78330 32.7843 54.7558
g_Y   0.05299  0.1812  0.39724  0.9168  6.1523
g_Z   0.14551  0.3438  0.59676  1.1107  4.3755
```

Comment: Nice catch. I have the same question of sampling from the posterior distribution of the numerator of a Bayes factor object, i.e., ***posterior(anovaBF())***.

Answer (score 1):

By `?anovaBF()`, you can check the model $y=\mu+X_1\theta_1+...+X_p\theta_p+\epsilon$, where $\mu$ is the grand mean, theta’s are the vectors of main-effect and interaction effects, $X$’s are corresponding design matrix, and epsilon is the error term. Hence, in your case, mcmc samples returned by `posterior(anovaBF())` are the estimates for the grand mean and condition effects (which explain why the figure is negative). The condition effects sum to zero.

Then, the posterior samples are the grand mean plus each condition effect.

Comment: You can use backticks for code formatting and mathjax for math formatting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not been able to find a satisfactory answer through the posterior generated by the BayesFactor package (though it is most likely because I am doing something wrong). However, I did find an alternative approach which might prove useful for others coming across this question.

Using the library 'bayesboot', I am able to get the posterior(95% HDI) as desired relatively easily. The code below demonstrates this approach. Simply refer to the 'hdi.low' and 'hdi.high' columns.

```
library(bayesboot)
bayes_A <- bayesboot(Data[Data$Y == "A",]$X, weighted.mean, use.weights = TRUE)
summary(bayes_A)

Summary of the posterior (with 95% Highest Density Intervals):
 statistic     mean       sd  hdi.low hdi.high
        V1 13.60795 1.875804 9.951562 17.23397
```